# windows mobile 6 application database connect with server database

Tags: sql-server, windows-mobile, c#-3.0, sql-server-ce, windows-7-x64

i am developing windows mobile application.i want to connect my local database with the server database.my device have LAN connection.How do i connect these two.please give me some links ..

Comment: Hi, I am a little bit confused. Either you have a local (on the mobile) and a server database or you have a server database that you want to access from your windows mobile device. The first requires data synchronization between the server and client database. The second simply needs the SqlCEClient and a working TCP/IP connection to the server.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure your device can browse to the server, like shown in the screenshot below:

[image: WM5 Screenshot]

Once you are able to access the server with some username and password, you use that same username and password in your SQL Connection string.

That should be all you need.

Answer (score 0):

If you want connect to a SQL Server (not SQLCE Server locally), first you need to import the data and sqlclient namespace (and add the references to the project).

```
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
```

then you need to build a connection string:

```
// Connection string
private string strConn =
    "data source=OurServer;" +
    "initial catalog=Northwind;" +
    "user id=DeliveryDriver;" +
    "pwd=DD;" +
    "workstation id=OurDevice;" +
    "packet size=4096;" +
    "persist security info=False;";
```

then you can create a connection:

```
// A connection, a command, and a reader
SqlConnection connDB = new SqlConnection(strConn);
```

and build a SQLCommand with a SQL query (ie "SELECT * FROM Products;"):

```
SqlCommand cmndDB =new SqlCommand(sqlQueryString, connDB);
```

the datareader can then be used to read the result:

```
SqlDataReader drdrDB;
```

now read thru the result:

```
try
{
    // Open the connection.
    connDB.Open();
    // Submit the SQL statement and receive
    // the SqlReader for the results set.
    drdrDB = cmndDB.ExecuteReader();
    // Read each row.
    while ( drdrDB.Read() )
    {
       //access fields of the result
    }
    drdrDB.Close();
}
...
//Close the connection
connDB.Close();
```

That is all.